Как получить иерархию данных для ViewModels из трех таблиц с помощью EF?
Запутался и не могу догнать как сделать)
Есть некие модели представления, и под них я сделал модели и сделал настройку связей (вроде правильно, всё ниже).
Не могу понять как получить данные из бд с помощью EF по трём таблицам и замапить в модели представления используя репозиторий. Как это всё собрать вместе?
Модели представления:
public class EducationalLevelPreparationVM
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string LevelName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ObservableCollection<EducationalDirectionTrainingVM> DirectionsTraining { get; set; } = new();
}

public class EducationalDirectionTrainingVM
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string DirectionCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string DirectionName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ObservableCollection<EducationalProfileVM> EducationalProfiles { get; set; } = new();
}

public class EducationalProfileVM
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string ProfileCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ProfileName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ObservableCollection<string> FormsOfTraining { get; set; } = new();
}

Модели:
public class EducationalLevelPreparation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string LevelName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class EducationalDirectionTraining
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DirectionCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string DirectionName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Guid EducationalLevelPreparationId { get; set; }
    public EducationalLevelPreparation EducationalLevelPreparation { get; set; }
}

public class EducationalProfile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ProfileCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ProfileName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Guid EducationalDirectionTrainingId { get; set; }
    public EducationalDirectionTraining EducationalDirectionTraining { get; set; }
}

Настроенные связи:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<EducationalLevelPreparation>()
        .HasMany<EducationalDirectionTraining>()
        .WithOne(x => x.EducationalLevelPreparation)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.EducationalLevelPreparationId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


    modelBuilder.Entity<EducationalDirectionTraining>()
        .HasMany<EducationalProfile>()
        .WithOne(x => x.EducationalDirectionTraining)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.EducationalDirectionTrainingId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}

Суть:
Уровни имеют несколько направлений, а направления имеют несколько профилей. (Связи вроде правильные)
Данные отображаются в TreeView, привязанный к
public ObservableCollection<EducationalLevelPreparationVM> Levels { get; set; } = new();
(там все уровни показываются, если я статично добавлю всю иерархию от руки)
А как с помощью EF, получить всю иерархию данных и засунуть в
public ObservableCollection<EducationalLevelPreparationVM> Levels { get; set; } = new();
вызывая метод Read() прокинутого репозитория.
Какая там должна быть последовательность действий?

Разобрался вроде как, если можно было как то лучше то подскажите)

Во ViewModelях изменил коллекции на ICollection типы.

В модели добавил эти же ICollection типы.

Код получения данных и маппинг:
public List<EducationalLevelPreparationVM> Read()
{
 using (var db = new DataContext())
 {
     return db.SettingLevels.Select(level => new 
EducationalLevelPreparationVM
     {
         Id = level.Id,
         LevelName = level.LevelName,
         DirectionsTraining = level.DirectionsTraining.Select(direction => new EducationalDirectionTrainingVM
         {
             Id = direction.Id,
             DirectionCode = direction.DirectionCode,
             DirectionName = direction.DirectionName,
             EducationalProfiles = direction.EducationalProfiles.Select(profile => new EducationalProfileVM
             {
                 Id = profile.Id,
                 ProfileCode = profile.ProfileCode,
                 ProfileName = profile.ProfileName
             }).ToList()
         }).ToList()
     }).ToList();
 }
 }



Что-то типа такого)

Не очень хорошее решение. 1. Вы намешали все в одну кучу, когда как у вас должна быть модель, которая работает с базой, получает нужные данные из базы и отдает модели. Условно говоря var items = someClass.GetItems();. В VM слое вы уже полученные данные преобразуете в VM любым удобным способом. 2. .ToList() - это "Ей база, дай мне все данные, я сам разберусь что с ними потом делать". Если у вас данных много, то это может быть очень большой проблемой. Вообще, когда база должна подгрузить нужные данные, вызывается обычно .Include().

@EvgeniyZ Чутка запутался, правильно я понимаю: 1 Vm обращается к прокинутому репозиторию, чтобы он вернул Model уже с данными (то есть в репозитории метод Read берет из бд данные сует их в модель и возвращает) 2 В VM я делаю маппинг из возвращенной Model в VM и сую в коллекцию, которая отображает иерархию данных 3 Беру данные не правильно и надо как-то через Include?

Представьте, что вы в реальной жизни должны написать отчет для своего босса в определенном формате. Вы запрашиваете данные из отдела кадров, которые дают в своем формате все нужные вам данные, затем вы запрашиваете выписку из банка, который тоже дает вам данные в своем формате, ну и так далее. Далее, уже на основе этих данных вы составляете свой отчет, "конвертируя" полученную информацию в то, что нужно боссу. Вот в программировании все аналогично. Расценивайте все слои, как мало связанные, отдельные друг от друга приложения, которые что-то делают и что-то возвращают.

Код из вопроса - это если брать пример с отчетом, то запросив данные из банка, банк заполняет за вас ваш отчет. Согласитесь, звучит... странно. Так что, модель должна возвращать конкретные, стандартные данные (модели), которые вы в любом месте приложения можете запросить и преобразовать во что угодно. Обычно делается отдельный класс, который уже общается с базой и у которого есть методы получения, добавления, удаления, и т.д., ну и уже этот класс везде и вызывается, а не база напрямую. 3. Да, почитайте про Include, сейчас более точно я вам увы, не скажу.

@EvgeniyZ То есть главная VM не обращается к репозиторию, а обращается к классу(некая модель имеющая коллекцию<модель>) и уже этот класс обращается к репозиторию, чтобы получить данные для своей коллекции<модель>, потом эта коллекция возвращается во главную VM, где происходит маппинг. Если это правильное понимание, то репозиторий возвращает всю иерархию через Include или же только верхний уровень данных без вложенности, а вложенности я получаю через другие классы(модели), которые обращаются к своим репозиториям для получения нужных данных и уже по очереди запихиваются по иерархии? запутался)

Код из этого ответа где у вас находится? В VM? Если в VM, то как я сказал выше, вы работаете с базой напрямую, дергая DataContext, когда как у вас должна быть отдельная модель, которая вернет вам модели по запросу, с которыми уже VM делает что надо. Если этот код в модели, то почему он работает с VM классами? Это нарушение MVVM, ибо модель не должна ничего знать про другие слои. Я вам сейчас говорю про то, что вы должны разделить этот код на две составляющие, VM и M, где в VM будет просто model.GetItems(), без прямого доступа к базе, ну данные уже преобразовывайте как надо и отображайте.

@EvgeniyZ Код в ответе это метод репозитория. То есть главная в VM в которую прокинут репозиторий обращается к этому методу, а уже метод возвращает List, но в методе и данные получаю и маппинг делаю(этот момент нужно разделить).

Ну вот и ваша проблема, ибо "репозитории" - это обычно слой модели, ну а почему вдруг ваша модель не только знает, но еще и создает VM объекты? В моделях должны быть только модели, не более. Как мне однажды один хороший знакомый сказал, вот есть на производстве лазерный станок, для него кто-то написал библиотеку, которая позволяет этим лазером управлять. Вот весь код этой библиотеки - это модель, которой без разницы как будет выполняться данный код, где, какой UI будет, и так далее. Она просто дает методы управления, не более. Также и у вас, работа с базой не должна ничего знать про VM.

@EvgeniyZ Если все обобщить выше сказанное, то Vm вызывает метод репозитория, чтоб тот вернул коллекцию<модель> с заполненными данными. В главной Vm из этих данных делаю vm слои и засовываю в коллекцию, которая уже отображает иерархию по биндингу.

Типа того. Самое стандартное преобразование будет примерно таким: foreach (var item in model.GetItems()) { Levels.Add(new () { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name ... }) }. Всякие new () {...} преобразования можно сделать как метод расширения, ну или любой другой способ, будет тогда Levels.Add(item.ToViewModel());, тут уже вариантов куча. Главное, разделите слои)

@EvgeniyZ Понял, спасибо

Вообще .ToList() это паразит, потому что: Во-первых, .ToArray() легче и быстрее работает. Во-вторых в 99,9% это используется из-за недостаточных знаний, как работать с данными и можно обойтись без зессмысленного копирования мегабайтов данных туда-сюда. И речь здесь не только о БД, а вообще о любых Linq запросах. Нет смысла создавать список, когда его возможности, а именно добавление и удаление элементов не требуются, верно?

@aepot понял, возьму на заметку
